# How do I filter items in an array based on a substring match?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am searching an array in jQuery,

```
var arr = ["mango","banana","jackfriut","apple","google"];
var removeItem = "google";   //works fine
var removeItem = "ogle";   //fails

arr = $.grep(arr, function(value) {
  return value != removeItem;
});
alert(arr)
```

When I am passing `"google"` then its working fine.
Please let me know that it should work when I pass only some content like `"ogle"`.
its like wildcard.

Comment: because there's no "ogle" in your array.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring

Comment: You also want answers using Java and JSP?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not using `indexOf()`?

Comment: @Turnip, thats not related to that, Please check the question.

Comment: @Khusboo it is absolutely related to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` for your condition

```
 var arr = ["mango","banana","jackfriut","apple","google"];
 var removeItem = "ogle";   //fails

 arr = $.grep(arr, function(value) {
    if(value.indexOf(removeItem) == -1)
       return value;
 });
 alert(arr)
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwud4x7L/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Exactly, this is what I want, its working fine..., thank you @Thinker..,

Comment: How to remove it from original array??

Comment: QThinker, Awesome answer...,

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQUery's built in `$.inArray` function.

```
var arr = ["mango","banana","jackfriut","apple","google"];

function inArray() {
    if($.inArray(value, arrayName) !== -1) {
        alert("Value is in array");
    } else {
        alert("Value is not in array");
    }
}
```

You can then call your function passing in the value you are looking for:

```
inArray("google");
```

Of course, the logic you choose to return in the function is up to you but this is the best way to check for values in an array.